# Django get_or_create() - Accented unicode characters match to existing objects

Tags: django

I have

```
combi, created = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(title=title)
```

once the object `Tina` is in db, I try to insert `Tinà`, but it is not being created even if `Tina` is different than `Tinà`.

why?  am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this might be a database issue. Most likely the underlying SQL COLUMN normalizes Tinà to Tina before doing any index look ups, thus `SELECT ... WHERE title ='Tinà'` is same as `SELECT ... WHERE title ='Tina'`

Please add some details about your database (schema dump?)

Smells like MySQL :)

Comment: you are probably right, because even ``Bla``=``Blä``. this is weird

Comment: The answer to your question "Are you missing something" is "You are missing a sane database software" :) You probably need to migrate your database collection (see the bug link for example).

Comment: yeah you are right. postgresql is the best one among all db softwares

Comment: "collection" ->  collation. Spelling error in my previous comment.